# Calculate Price Range in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, range, calculator

How I should approach the JavaScript (can't use jQuery) to change a price using these range calculations:

[image]

I found this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tMqX4/) but it uses jQuery . It is very similar to what I want to achieve although I didn't see a range code in it, just values .

ie: `your price : 200  so multiple by 0.23` refer to chart. So if I have the price `200` I want to get the value `0.23`.

Is there an easier way, then doing the following code below?

```
  if (maxValue <= 100) {
        minvalue = 250
  }

  if (maxValue <= 250) {
        chartMaxY = 500
  ...
```

Or declaring values?

```
   var pricerange = [100, 250,, 1000, 2500, 50000, ];


    if (maxValue <= pricerange[i]) {
        minvalue = pricerange[i];
```

Comment: I don't understand the question . . .

Comment: Whatever you do, ensure you multiply all your values by 100, do your math, then divide by 100. Douglas Crockford told me to.

Comment: jQuery would not matter here, you don't use it for things like this.

Comment: Why on earth would you use jQuery to do a calculation in the first place? Do you know what jQuery even is?

Comment: @godisgood I need to create a javascript function that determines a multiplication  value based on large or small the price is. Refer to this [range calculations](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nOCI9.jpg)

Comment: Ok thanks, any ideas on the javascript ?

Comment: A way you would make a price range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two arrays, one will be the range and the other what value you should get. For example:

```js
var value = 1100; // is between 1000-2500 so we should get 0.20
var chartValue;

var priceRange = [ 100, 250, 1000, 2500, 5000 ];
var priceValue = [ 0.23, 0.12, 0.20, 0.19, 0.19 ];

for(range in priceRange) 
   if (value >= priceRange[range]) 
        chartValue = priceValue[range];

alert(chartValue)// Gives 0.20
```

This works because a new value is assigned when a higher range is detected. For example what happens in the example above is like so: It's higher than 100 set chartValue to `0.23`, it's higher than `250` set chartValue to `0.12`, it's higher than `1000` set chartValue to `0.20`. But it's not greater than `2500` so that will be the last time it changes. Notice that how this is setup we used only one `greater-than` comparison, and re-setting the value makes the ranges we want.

Comment: I was writing like 15 different if statements and it wasn't working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would likely write two functions with all hard-coded values.

```
function fiveYear (price) {
  if (price < 100) {
    throw new Erorr('price must be at least 100')
  } else if (price > 100 && price < 250) {
    return 0.23

  // .. etc ..
}
```

If the values will change often, you'll need to come up with a more general solution, like putting the values in a database.

Comment: Yea it is running offline(on ipad actually) , so I cant use a database . I see what you mean tho . I will try it thanks you.

Comment: Why not use an array with loops?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek loops are definitely cleaner today. Business logic usually gets messy tho so i don't even bother. Clean tests tho for sure.